# Buffer Security Check (/GS) expected cookie doesn't match its own complement

Tags: windows, visual-c++, driver, stack-overflow, windbg

I have some crash dump that was caused by a stack overrun. The driver was compiled with `/GS`, so when the security cookie gets corrupted, it triggers a bugcheck. No surprise there. However, the arguments are:

```
DRIVER_OVERRAN_STACK_BUFFER (f7)
A driver has overrun a stack-based buffer.  This overrun could potentially
allow a malicious user to gain control of this machine.
DESCRIPTION
A driver overran a stack-based buffer (or local variable) in a way that would
have overwritten the function's return address and jumped back to an arbitrary
address when the function returned.  This is the classic "buffer overrun"
hacking attack and the system has been brought down to prevent a malicious user
from gaining complete control of it.
Do a kb to get a stack backtrace -- the last routine on the stack before the
buffer overrun handlers and bugcheck call is the one that overran its local
variable(s).
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffd000a91557dd, Actual security check cookie from the stack
Arg2: 00008505f890dcd0, Expected security check cookie
Arg3: ffffd466d2205dcd, Complement of the expected security check cookie
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero
```

Note that `Arg2 != ~Arg3`. In all similar crash dumps I've seen, they always matched.

The security check cookie is calculated by XORing the `___security_cookie` with the return address. Then when checking it, it calculates the same thing. I always assumed the complement was there for redundancy, since they always return 4 arguments.

What could it mean that the expected cookie and its complement don't match?

Comment: Since nobody else has answered, I'll hazard a guess that the system keeps two copies of the cookie, one of which is complemented.  Either the original copy or the complemented copy have been corrupted by the same bug that corrupted the stack.  (Or perhaps it was the cookies that were corrupted and the stack was fine!)